# using uniform for passing texture objects

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

[In this page of learn openGL](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Shaders) we define and use uniform variables like this:

```
int vertexColorLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "ourColor");
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
glUniform4f(vertexColorLocation, 0.0f, greenValue, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Basically you:

1. get the uniform variable location and
2. assign the value to that location
   This is the part in the text where we hadn't learnt about textures, but,

[When it came to textures](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures), the page says:

> The fragment shader should also have access to the texture object, but how do we pass the texture object to the fragment shader? GLSL has a built-in data-type for texture objects called a sampler that takes as a postfix the texture type we want e.g. sampler1D, sampler3D or in our case sampler2D. We can then add a texture to the fragment shader by simply declaring a uniform sampler2D that we later assign our texture to.

and does this to the fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord);
}
```

**So my confusion is:** where is the uniform location fetching and data binding done in here, how does the fragment shader know which texture object is the uniform for?

Below is the codes for quick reference:

Firstly we load/generate the texture using this code:

```
unsigned int texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
// set the texture wrapping/filtering options (on the currently bound texture object)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
// load and generate the texture
int width, height, nrChannels;
unsigned char *data = stbi_load("container.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
if (data)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
}
stbi_image_free(data);
```

**The vertex shader is like this:**

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

**The fragment shader is like this:**

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord);
}
```

and the drawing in the mainloop using this:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Comment: Your question is already answered in the section "Texture Units" in the very same document you linked.

Comment: Buy default almost all uniforms are initialized by 0 respectively 0.0. If the texture is bound to texture unit 0, then it is not necessary to assign 0 to the texture sampler uniform.